# Mysql and JDBC returned stale data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions

We are facing a strange issue with mysql data. We have a seqgenerator table which holds the current seq of the id. Every time an order is placed my application queries the seqgenerator table and updates one number and saves it back in the seqgenerator.

The query we are using to fetch is "select order_id from order_seq where appid = ? for update" 
Query to update "update order_seq set order_id = ? where appid = ?"

This was working fine until last week, last week the select query returned id which was already used one day back and the id got reset and started incrementing from there due to which we have overridden 1 days orders.

Comment: Sounds like your design is bad too. Allowing data to get corrupted because of id reuse is just sloppy. It should fail immediately.

Comment: I agree it was a mistake with the coding , We are using the id in nosql database, the engineer by mistake used save or update style of coding.  We are fixing that anyways. but I would like to know how the mysql has reset the id suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is just very bad.

First of all, Id should always be unique, this would have prevented your data from being overwritten.

Also SQL has an Auto-Increment field, so you don't have to update your ID by one each time

> Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically
> when a new record is inserted into a table.
>
> Often this is the primary key field that we would like to be created
> automatically every time a new record is inserted
>
> Source:
> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: And if he is using a string for his `ID`, the he can generate unique ID in java using `java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()`;

Comment: Auto increment is not possible in our case because we are using the generated id to store in an no sql database. We are fixing the validation part how ever i would like to check how the mysql returned old data despite using "for update" in the query.

Comment: @sathishyellanty are you using correct transaction handling?

Comment: used the highest transaction 
con = getConnection();
con.setAutoCommit(false);
con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);

// query and update to mysql

con.commit();